# Set multiple options javascript (MooTools) object at once

Tags: javascript, class, mootools

I've got something like this

```
var obj = new someClass(el, {
    onOne: function () {
        doThis();
    },
    onTwo: function () {
        doThis();
    },
    onThree: function () {
        doThis();
    },
    onFour: function () {
        doThat();
    }
});
```

So, the first three events will have the same result, only the fourth is different. Like this, it seems kind of repetitive, so I was hoping that I could do something like this

```
var obj = new someClass(el, {
    onOne: 
    onTwo: 
    onThree: function () {
        doThis();
    },
    onFour: function () {
        doThat();
    }
});
```

But I can't.
I wonder, if there's some way I *can* do something similar (without changing the class itself). In think it would make the code clearer and better maintainable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about predefining the function?

```
var myHandler = function() {
    doThis();
};

var obj = new Class(el, {
    onOne: myHandler,
    onTwo: myHandler,
    onThree: myHandler,
    onFour: function () {
        doThat();
    }
});
```

If you know keys of the object you may additionally try working with `for` loop, for example

```
var passIt = { 
    onFour: function() { 
        doThat(); 
    } 
};

var keys = ['onOne', 'onTwo', 'onThree'];
var l = keys.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    passIt[keys[i]] = myHandler;
}

var obj = new Class(el, passIt);
```

Comment: Although not what I was hoping for, this is the best answer to my question. Also an upvote for the clever second solution, from which my (current) implementation would not really benefit, but I certainly can see some neat stuff being done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are [first-class citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) in the JavaScript world. Unless you've omitted extra processing in your anonymous functions, the following should work:

```
var obj = new Class(el, { 
    onOne   : doThis
  , onTwo   : doThis
  , onThree : doThis
  , onFour  : doThat
})
```

Which creates three method aliases for `doThis` on `obj`, named `onOne`, `onTwo`, and `onThree`, and a method alias for `doThat` on `obj` named `onFour`.

When you invoke `obj.onOne(...)`, it's [equivalent to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) `doThis.call(obj, ...)`.

**Note**: I'm not sure you're using MooTool's `Class()` constructor properly in your example. Reading the [docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class), it looks like `Class` excepts only one argument, a `properties` object (or function) that the newly created object will inherit from. If the code doesn't work, try removing `el` and adding an `'Extends' : el` property to the object literal. I've never used MooTools personally, though, so I'm not sure what to expect.

Comment: where he says `new Class`, he means `new ClassInstance` and Class references somethign that constructor object has defined previously. in his definition, his constructor function is set to take 2 arguments - an element and an options object, which is where the event handlers are coming from. I have edited the original question to reflect this. p.s. go away with this @fat syntax, its fugly. :)

Comment: I was wondering, because he has mootools tagged, and it appears to have a global Class() convenience function, but the signature in the docs doesn't match his. (And I'd argue that beautiful syntax is syntax that helps you spot errors in your code, but let's leave the religious wars to others. ;))